# How to join the column from Table B to Table A on some condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

Before posting my question here, I was researching the other posts on stackoverflow and other resources. They haven't solved my problem(. Can you help me? Lets go to the point.

I have my  `movies` table with columns(`id`, `name`, `kind_id`, `production_year`) and i have `movies_info` table with (`id`, `movie_id`, `info`).
I want to join my `info` column to the `movies` table. And then select everything from `movies` and the joined column `info` on some condition.
I have built the next query, but somehow it still doesn't work correctly.

```
    String query = "SELECT m.*, m_i.info FROM movies m " +
                   "INNER JOIN movie_info m_i ON m.id = m_i.movie_id "+
                   "WHERE m.production_year <=' " + array[1] + "' 
                   AND m.production_year >= ' " + array[0] +" 'AND m.kind_id=1";
```

i think here is something wrong with my `where`condition. 
I hope the question was clear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible SQL Injection.

Comment: @lad2025 its for the app for my own use.

Comment: where syntax looks ok.  You probably just don't have a match.

Comment: @Frisbee Is the inner join the right kind of join for this usage? Am i right?

Comment: what's in your array ? Years ? is the production_year column declared as string or number ?

Comment: Is it throwing an error?  The question is not clear.

Comment: @ThomasG array for integers. yes, years. i have the right output for everything except the joined info column.(

Comment: @Frisbee not errors. i just wanna to be sure that my query is built in the right way, that i can start to find the bugs in another part of the program

Comment: if you your `production_year` column is declared as number, start by removing the quotes surrounding the array values: `WHERE m.production_year <= " + array[1] + " 
                   AND m.production_year >=  " + array[0] +" AND m.kind_id=1";`

Comment: Show some effort.  Then what doesn't work correctly?  How can we help you if you have not described the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

```
String query = "SELECT m.*, m_i.info FROM movies m " +
               "LEFT JOIN movie_info m_i ON m.id = m_i.movie_id "+
               "WHERE m.production_year <=' " + array[1] + "' 
               AND m.production_year >= ' " + array[0] +" 'AND m.kind_id=1";
```